# Add editText on action bar

Tags: java, android

I wonder how to achieve this ?

I have a search icon in action bar as image below

[image]

When it is clicked, I want the action bar change to `editText` and has a search `icon` beside the `editText`

I know how to make an editText with an image, but how to put the editText on the action bar like image below ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the SearchView or Search Widget

[Check it out here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget)

Answer (score 2):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search);

LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.search, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

create layout search with your EditText.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:focusable="true" >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_query"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_search_edit_text"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do I need to use intent ? Assume the search icon is in Activity A, when press, it change to EditText and I would like to show the related data below

Comment: Yes .http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/ here is exactly what u want..

Answer (score 1):

Implementation search menu item:

[Check it out here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/)